# Eclipse Debugging Run Methods

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, methods

it's probably really easy but I still don't know how to do this.

Is it possible to run a method while a program in Java is running in debug-mode in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, open the "Display view" to run any code you want at the position you're currently at.
See:
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdisplay%2Fref-display_view.htm

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode, it will open a new perspective and it's going to show the workflow of your Main method, including all the methods invocations during it's execution, which variable's values has changed, everything that happen to the beginning until the end of your Main class code.

May you check this link, got a lot of [usefull](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=336709&seqNum=2)  information.